# API Credentials in Docker Images ran on AWS ECS-Tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, rest, oauth-2.0, amazon-ecs

I have a few images that are ran through ECS on AWS which make get/post requests to an API. When I authenticate for the API, I have my credentials stored as variables.

Two Questions.

1. Is this safe/best practice when authenticating for an API in a Docker Image?
2. Is there an AWS service that can help me authenticate for the API?

NOTE: the API is not boto3.

Comment: When you say variables, do you mean ECS environment variables? Or variables inside your software that is running in the docker container on ECS? Or something else?

Comment: variables inside of the code running in the docker container on ECS.

Comment: How do those variables get populated? Are the credentials hard-coded in your app's source code?

Comment: yes, when I build the image they are hard coded in the python file.

Comment: Yeah, that's not good. Look at my answer for a better solution.

Comment: One more question. So using Secrets Manager passes in environment variables to the container. The function i am using to generate an Oauth token takes in key value parameters to generate that token (in python). Do you know how I would get secrets managers to populate the secret into the function?

Comment: SecretsManager doesn't populate the secrets into anything. ECS reads the values from SecretsManager and injects them into your container as environment variables. In your code, you would change your variables like `key = "abc123"` to something like `key = env["KEY"]`. How exactly you do that depends entirely on the programming language you are using, which you haven't specified in your question.

Comment: I am using python.  If I create a secret with the key being "password" and the value pair being the password , I believe I would do  `api_password=os.environment['password']`and pass  the variable api_password into the function that generates the Oauth token.

Comment: That sounds right. You can test all this locally as well. Passing environment variables to Docker containers is the standard way to do this sort of thing in any environment, even locally.

Comment: thank you so much man, really needed this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest storing the authentication credentials in AWS SecretsManager, or AWS SSM Parameter Store, and using [this method](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-data-security-container-task/) to provide those credentials as environment variables to your ECS containers.